# Symfony cache:clear command changes folder owner

Tags: php, symfony, caching

I have a Symfony project in production and after running `sudo php app/console cache:clear --env=prod`, the folder's permissions become

`drwxr-xr-x 11 root     root     4096 Feb 29 15:08 prod`

This doesn't allow the user `www-data`(apache default user) to access it anymore.

How can I clear the cache and have www-data read/write to the cache folder?

Also, running `php console cache:clear` for the dev mode I get
`The stream or file "../app/logs/dev.log" could not

   be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied` and dev.log file has been created with following permissions:
`-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data 2840530 Feb 29 15:01 dev.log`

Comment: `sudo -u {owner} php cache:clear -e prod`

Comment: I dont suggest you cleaning cache with this command. I found it is not always deleting those files. Instead manually delete prod and dev directories inside cache/

Comment: dont run it as sudo.  Unless you specify, cache:clear will carry out a 'warmup' once its cleared cache. Which means it creates the basic folder structure of the cache directories. The resultant permissions will be root (if run from sudo)

Comment: It's not only the cache clearing command. It's also the database create, schema update and everything that tries to write in dev.log

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See "Setting up Permissions" in http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html#configuration-and-setup.

If you use Ubuntu you can use `setfacl`

```
sudo setfacl -R -m u:www-data:rwX -m u:`whoami`:rwX app/cache app/logs
sudo setfacl -dR -m u:www-data:rwx -m u:`whoami`:rwx app/cache app/logs
```

**EDIT:**

```
$ rm -rf var/cache/* var/logs/* var/sessions/*

$ HTTPDUSER=`ps axo user,comm | grep -E '[a]pache|[h]ttpd|[_]www|[w]ww-data|[n]ginx' | grep -v root | head -1 | cut -d\  -f1`
$ sudo chmod -R +a "$HTTPDUSER allow delete,write,append,file_inherit,directory_inherit" var
$ sudo chmod -R +a "`whoami` allow delete,write,append,file_inherit,directory_inherit" var
```

If there is no command setfacl on your pc you need install it;

```
sudo apt-get install acl
```

Comment: I've just ran these commands, but the dev.log file is still not writeable. I can't run any command. `-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data 3083769 Feb 29 15:36 dev.log
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data    1728 Feb 29 14:51 prod.log
`

Comment: You getting error about only logs or cache still throwing errors ?

Comment: Only logs. Cache never threw errors. It's just that the command is trying to write into dev.log.

Comment: Yeah, after they got deleted, they were generated with the following permissions: `-rw-rw-r--+ 1 www-data www-data 342359 Feb 29 15:44 dev.log
-rw-rw-r--+ 1 www-data www-data    859 Feb 29 15:52 prod.log
` which seems ok.

Comment: Yeah, cause some commands calling from your web server ( apache , nginx, etc ). You need work with that group.

Comment: Great, at least I got that one right. Thanks for the tips.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running console/bin as root?
If you are running a long script but try :

```
chown -R webuser:webuser /var
```

If you enter the command directly , please

```
su webuser
```

Answer (score -1):

We run into the same problem, and we ended up running the cache:clear command as the Apache user.

The other option is to have a script run the cache clear command as sudo, and then reinitialise folder permissions.

Comment: Not my downvote, but running console commands as sudo will lead you into a **whole** world of pain.